# How to create small table on right side of HTML page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a minimum-width two column html table on the right side of an HTML page.

Current ideas:

- Should I create a third column in front of my values and somehow maximize its width leaving two compact columns all the way to the right?
- Should I be wrapping the entire table in a `<div>` and using some right justification?
- I'm using Bootstrap CSS, is there an even easier way to do this with a JS class?

Thank you in advance,

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <td>SPACER</td>
        <td>PRICE UPDATE: </td>
        <td>{{price_update}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SPACER</td>
        <td>POSITION UPDATE: </td>
        <td>{{pos_update}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: If you show us what you have tried we might be able to help better

Comment: My apologies for not including the html snippet above initially, that was an oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little reading up on the bootstrap grid system may help (http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works).

You can use offset and the columns to do this pretty easily. for example:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-9 col-xs-3">
<!-- insert table here -->
</div>
```

Bootstrap works in 12s (which is why you need the offset of 9, or whatever will offset the size of the column you need). The `xs` is the screen size you want it to be displayed on, so in this case `xs` will display on the right hand side of every screen size but if you want it displayed on an iPad or PC only you'll have to change that, and then you can add how you want it displayed for smaller devices.

Also make sure you put all columns in a container and a row.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The link you sent was very helpful and an associated one also helped.  

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/

Comment: @TravisMillburn You're welcome/ Yea that article is superb and a must read for anyone getting started with (or with limited understanding of) Bootstrap. It's a great framework as well!